# ios unregisterForRemoteNotifications does not work

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to get my device unregistered from the remote notification services in my app, so I tried to use `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] unregisterForRemoteNotifications]`.  But this does not work. My app still shows up on the `notifications` section of my iPhone's `settings` app. Is there any other way I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

It is still there but it won't receive any notifications. That is the default behavior, once you registered your app will remain in the notification center and it will be activated/ deactivated when you register/unregister for remote notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Unregister function is not related to iOS app setting.

Only if you turn on the setting and register notification by function, you can get the notification successfully.

If even one of them is off, you should not receive any notification.